# R macros to enable user defined input similar to %let in SAS

Tags: r, automation, macros, sas, user-defined-functions

I am trying to automate a particular process in R, where essentially the code remains the same but the input files imported change- the path and most of the file name is the same only one word changes- and certain variable names change. 
I would like to make these changes user defined: much like %let in SAS. where i can call a value with &.

For example if i have this particular import code:

```
Category_sales<- read.csv("C:/Projects/Consumption curves/UKPOV/excel files/MSP_product_CC_2009_salespercap.csv")
```

Where I would like only the word MSP to change depending on what the user wants.
In SAS I would define a macrovariable like say %let metric=MSP

and replace the code as

```
`C:/Projects/Consumption curves/UKPOV/excel files/&metric_product_CC_2009_salespercap.csv`
```

Also If I have a variable say **MaxGNI** and I would like only the GNI part to be user defined/replaced like **Max&econvar** where I could have **econvar** defined as **%let econvar= GNI** or any other metric.

I am looking for something similar in R however.

Comment: Maybe `file.choose()`, or use `metric <- "MSP"`, then use `myCSV <- paste("C:/x/y/", metric, "blabla.csv")` to create a path to the file, then use `Category_sales <- read.csv(myCSV)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can accomplish this task using the `paste0` function.

```
metric <- "MSP"
infile <- paste0("C:/Projects/Consumption curves/UKPOV/excel files/",metric,"_product_CC_2009_salespercap.csv")
Category_sales <- read.csv(infile)
```

or wrapped in a function

```
readCSV <- function(var) {
       metric <- var
       infile <- paste0("C:/Projects/Consumption curves/UKPOV/excel files/",metric,"_product_CC_2009_salespercap.csv")
       return(infile)

}

Category_sales <- read.csv(readCSV('MSP'))
```

You can apply the same logic to all the bits that need to be replaced in your string.

Regarding to variable names you can do:

`eval(parse(....))` will work

```
data1 <- data.frame(column1 = 1:10, column2 = letters[1:10])
txt <- "data1$column2"

> eval(parse(text = txt))
 [1] a b c d e f g h i j
Levels: a b c d e f g h i j
```

For your particular case you can replace `txt` with the same `paste0` logic to build your variable names.

Full explanation in [this SO Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17792929/pass-string-as-name-of-attached-data-column-name)

Hope it helps

Comment: The first solution is great. However I also wanted to know if this is possible for variables like say. Min_max_Ratio_smoothGNI <-MaxGNIPPP_smooth/MinGNIPPP_smooth    where I want GNIPPP to be replaced with another string which is user defined

Comment: how are you planning to use those variables? reporting? modelling?  you can follow the same logic

Comment: I have expanded my answer to cover the 2nd part of your original question