# R SAS macro like expression

Tags: r, function

Firstly I aplogise because this question has no doubt been answered in another page eg
[How do I use a macro variable in R? (Similar to %LET in SAS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28484072/how-do-i-use-a-macro-variable-in-r-similar-to-let-in-sas) and [Pass string as name of attached data column name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17792929/pass-string-as-name-of-attached-data-column-name) but I’ve read them, watched Youtube tutorials, thought that the function command was what I wanted and I just can’t get it to work. I’m very new to programming as a whole, and only few days in for R, and I’m sure I’m missing something due to my lack of experience or understanding of even where to start.

In SAS I would do it like this

```
%Macro DV (var1, var2);
Proc mixed …
Model &var1 = &var2 …
Data &var1_&var2…
%mend DV;
%DV (VAS, Hyd)
%DV (SOM, Hyd)
%DV (GAS, Hyd)
```

The variables (eg. VAS, Hyd) that I’m calling in are column labels, they get called in, the column analysed in a mixed model and, with a bit more code, the dataset gets exported with a filename according to the variables analysed.
I’m not trying to do a lmer in R I’m using the rmcorr package and want to change the columns that get analysed.
The original expression, that works, looks like

```
VASCor.rmc <- rmcorr(participant = Subject, measure1 = Hyd, measure2 = VAS, dataset = mydata)
plot(VASCor.rmc,mydata, overall = T, lty=1, xlab = "Hyd", ylab = "VAS")
```

A working dataset can be found below. So just working on the first expression I tried the following, thinking that the var1 and var2 would get inserted in the correct places but I just end up with an error "object 'var2' not found".

```
Allrmcorr <- function(var1, var2){
var1.var2.rmc <- rmcorr(participant = Subject, measure1 = var2, measure2 = var1 , dataset = Results2)
}
Allrmcorr("VAS","Hyd")
Allrmcorr("VAS","Hyd")
```

I've attempted a number of expressions and probably spent long enough trying to figure it out to have just rewritten the expression time, I'm not closer but being stubborn I want to know the better way for next time. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
mydata <- data.frame(
Subject = c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3),
Time = c(1:5,1:5,1:5),
VAS= runif(15),
Hyd =runif(15),
GAS= runif(15)
)
```

Comment: Without knowing anything about the `rmcorr` function, it looks like you just need to `return` your variable that you create. Add `return(var1.var2.rmc)` to the end of your function and you should see the value. You'd then create your new variables like `vas.hyd.rmc <- Allrmcorr("VAS", "Hyd")`

Comment: There is no need for a return statement in this case. R always returns the last value in a function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not familiar with rmcorr but your problem stems from how your function takes input paramets. Look carefully at your code:

`rmcorr(participant = Subject, measure1 = var2, measure2 = var1 , dataset = Results2)`

takes `measure1` and `measure` as *bare names* input (so, a language element, not a string literal like `"var1"` (in quotes).

While you pass string literals to the function with `Allrmcorr("VAS","Hyd")`, rmcorr wants *bare names* that it evaluets in them frame of `dataset`. All this is probably a bit complicated an off-putting if you are new to R. I recommend reading "Advanced R" by Hadley Wickham if you want to dive deeper into the topic (especially the chapters on functions and lazy evaluation).

A simple solution to your problem - which is similar to how macro variables work - is constructing your expression as a string and then evaluating it:

```
Allrmcorr <- function(var1, var2, dat){
  ds <- dat
  eval(parse(text = (sprintf(
    "rmcorr(participant = Subject, measure1 = %s, measure2 = %s, dataset = ds)", var1, var2
  ))))
}

Allrmcorr("VAS", "Hyd", mydata)
```

This has **severe disadvantages** when it comes to performance and debuggability of your code; however, I was not able to find a better solution to your problem since the internal implementation of `rcmorr` is somewhat weird.

Comment: `get()` may not work since variable by itself does not exist in global environ. The `rmcorr` method references the column from *dataset* arg.

Comment: Hmm it doesn't have to be in the _global_ environment for get to work, but I am also not 100% sure get will work here. Maybe of op produces a reproducible example we can play around a bit.  `get(var2, Results2)` or simpler `Result2[[var2]]` should work in any case, but this is a bit cumbersome.

Comment: It may not be OP's fault but authors of package. Seeing their [source code](https://github.com/cran/rmcorr/blob/master/R/rmcorr.R), params are expected as *symbol* types and then `eval()` returns the value. Most functions usually receive string params to allow the dynamic nature OP requires. I may raise an issue on their repo.

Comment: @StefanF I've added a reproducible example now, my apologies for not doing that earlier. Thank you, I've had a go at your suggestions get(var1) get(var2, Results2) and Results2[[var2]] but they don't seem to work.

Comment: @Parfait By that does it mean that it's not possible? I'm happy to raise it with the authors since I have been in contact with them previously, though you obviously have a much better understanding of what's going on than I do.

Comment: Okay I have a solution. Im between doors and I will try to add some explanation to the answer later. It is very ugly by R standards, I hope someone else comes up with something better.

Comment: I raised an [issue](https://github.com/cran/rmcorr/blob/master/R/rmcorr.R) on their Git repo referencing this question. I even played around as @StefanF does with `eval(parse(...))` which became messy and not recommended. Use this solution in the meanwhile until their response or package update. Authors seem active as repo shows some update 5 days ago.

Comment: @Parfait I think you might want to contact the author directly. You posted your issue to a cran-mirror repository, that is not connected to the author at all